# How expand an equation in powers of two variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let

$$
\varphi=\int\frac{dr}{r^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{b^{2}}-\left(1-\frac{s}{r}\right)\frac{1}{r^{2}}}}
$$

Is it possible to expand the above equation in powers of $\frac{s}{r}$?.

I know that after expanding and taking the leading order term in this formula, then the integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ gives

$
\delta\varphi=\frac{2s}{b}
$

However, I could never get this approximation, Does anyone know how expand the above equation in terms of $\frac{s}{r}$?

Comment: Let $t=\frac{1}{r}$; you have $dt=-\frac{dr}{r^2}$.

Comment: hjpotter92, how to expand the above equation in powers of $s/r$?